# Why am I reading 22VDC / 69VAC when measuring between myself touching a MacBook and ground?

Tags: voltage, multimeter, earth, voltmeter

If I put the positive probe of my multimeter on earth, and touch the negative probe with my hand, while another hand is touching the metal surface of my MacBook, I get around 22VDC or 69VAC.
I cannot figure out why this happens. If I replace the MacBook with a li-ion battery, I get floating readings, if I try with a DC power supply, either positive or negative, I get nothing else.

This even happens when the MacBook is not plugged into it's charger, so it's not being connected to earth at any point.
This behaviour defies my understanding of electrical engineering, and I would appreciate if someone could shine a light so I can understand how this is possible.

Thanks

Comment: you are a big antenna

Comment: this is a FAQ, but I can't find the other.

Comment: Ohm’s Law says your lower  impedance relative to the 10MOhm DMM  couples this Voltage as a voltage to the DMM. Understanding the stray impedance and stray voltage present  is the result of these experiments.

Comment: What 'ground' is your DMM touching? Ground is a relative concept...

Comment: The EMI filter in your PSU has Y-type caps connected from live to earth and neutral to earth to keep switching noise out of the power line. Connected one way, the Y cap to live will bring the case to line potential (at very low current insufficient to hurt you.) For two-prong supplies where possible, simply reverse the plug connection to the outlet and the high measurement will greatly decline. This is exactly how my Microsoft Surface book (titanium case) operates. I feel a shock with the plug inserted one way. No shock the other way. An AC-hot tester will alarm one way and not the other, too.

Comment: @hekete From your comment I realised I used "ground" instead of "earth", which is what I meant. In my language ground and earth are the same word.

Comment: @jonk The behaviour I experienced happens also when the MacBook is unplugged from it's charger. The MacBook is not connected to earth in any way, so the Y cap should not be the issue (I think).

Comment: @sunnyskyguy I understand that the voltage of the metal I am touching will be read through the DMM, my question is why is there a voltage potential between my MacBook case and earth. I am assuming measuring between the case itself and earth will give the same results.

Comment: @Cubox your MacBook has no Earth connection. So how would it not have a voltage difference?

Comment: I am betting that there is a cord plugged into AC nearby, and that there might be a faulty ground to earth.  69 volts AC is a load of inductance, and unhealthy for it to be passing through you.  Nature doesn’t do AC, it is an artifact of how we mechanistically move magnet in proximity to coil with circular motors, hence the sine geometry of the transverse wave.  Remember that the lead wires are capable of induction, so if you have them tangled around an AC-connected cord, voila the 69 volt AC.  F.

Comment: @hekete The voltage difference between ground and myself not touching the MacBook is floating (less than 500mV), but jumps to 23VDC when I touch the MacBook case. Since I am unable to get the same behaviour touching anything else (another battery), the voltage difference must come from somewhere

Comment: @francis DMM leads are not close to any AC cord.

Comment: After more testing, I get 52uA AC of current flowing FROM earth to the MacBook case through me, and 3uA DC. Reading frequency gives me 50Hz. When not touching the macbook case, only 1uA AC goes from earth to me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately my assumptions were incorrect.
The part that defied logic to me was that the reading would still persist when the MacBook got unplugged from the charger. However the metal case around the charger plug is the culprit.
When unplugging the plug, I was touching both the computer and the charger with the same hand, leading to the wrong result.

If properly unplugged and while not touching the charger plug itself, I do not read 23VDC/69VAC. The explanations in the comments do apply in that case, thanks.
It's only leakage current being seen from the charger.